# Buffer size is not correct

Tags: c, malloc, buffer

I'm creating the following buffer:

```
char *buffer;
int buffer_size = 1024;
buffer = (char*) ( malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char) );
```

Then when I do:

```
int actual_size = sizeof(buffer);
printf("Size: %d", actual_size);
```

What it prints is:

```
size: 4
```

While I would expect it to be 1024, why is this?

Comment: Pointers ain't arrays, grab a good C book... Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: You're right :P This is a basic question, and now I think about it I obviously know the answer to my own question.

Comment: good to hear! If you think about it a bit and you then know the solution, that means you got the point(er) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not work like that

```
 sizeof(buffer);
```

returns the size of `buffer` which is a pointer, not an array. If you have an array such as the following

```
 char szArray[100];
```

then

```
 sizeof(szArray);
```

would return 100 because `szArray` is an array, but a **pointer** is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you print out the size of the variable *buffer*, which is *a pointer to a buffer* of chars.
Pointer to a char array weights directly 4 bytes in the memory, that's why it prints to you 4 instead of 1024.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `sizeof(buffer)` is size of pointer, so result on 32-bit machine is 4 in 64-bit machine is 8.

---

```
char arr[1024];
int size = sizeof(arr); //=1024
```

Here we measure size of array, not pointer. You need to remember that pointer act like array, but is not array. Actually in really low level they look the same, however in `C` level there is differences.

Comment: Can you give info about _those differences_?